# Don't get return value every time I access the page

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a webservice page currently on localhost which is based on PHP that should return me a JSON Array with 3 random rows. It seems to work but not always. Sometimes I need to reload the page 2-3 times to get it. 
My webservice will work together with Android this is just for some context.
My question: what changes my code needs to be done in order to get what I need every time I open the page?
Here is the code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "webappdb";

$sql = "SELECT word_en, word_da, article_da FROM words WHERE cate_id='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";


$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array("word_en"=>$row[0],"word_da"=>$row[1],"article_da"=>$row[2]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: you can add a while loop that says if the json response is empty repeat the loop but if the json response is 1 or more echo the json encoded array.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? What is the difference with the working case? How do you spot the difference? Is there a relevant stacktrace?

Comment: @ibizaman when it works I get unformatted JSON array. Just what I need. When it doesn't work I get only a blank screen. No errors in it.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is known to be very slow. It could be a query timeout. Does your script take a long time to run (more than a second)? Also, how many rows are in your table?

Comment: Turn on error reporting - blank screens are not much use

Comment: I have 195 rows. When it works it takes less than a second to load the contents. Sometimes I even need to reload the page ~7 times to make it work. Sometimes it works from the first time.

Comment: I have no experience in PHP. This code I found in a random tutorial on youtube but can anyone please tell me if there is a command in PHP to check for an empty page/JSON ?
One more thing - according to @ibizaman ORDER BY RAND() is a slow thing. What is the faster way in MySql to get a random value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json data can only be displayed if it is properly encoded to utf8. If you're using data which might contain special chars like ä ö or ü, you'll need to utf8_encode your output before sending it to json_encode. Not properly encoded data will result in empty outputs just like you described.

Comment: nice noticing. I need change encoding to utf8_encode to my data. I am on my way to do it.

Comment: your remark was right. Now that I changed encoding to utf8_encode I get return values every time I load the page. But I don't get Danish characters, instead I get this "{"word_en":"onion","word_da":"l\u00f8g","article_da":"et"}"

Comment: I am marking this answer as a solution because it has shown me what is the problem.